# Setting NTFS Permissions With Powershell

Tags: powershell, ntfs

Using the following powershell I have set the NTFS Permissions for a folder for full control. For some reason this is only applying to the folder and not its contents. I followed the instructions located [here](http://techibee.com/powershell/grant-fullcontrol-permission-to-usergroup-on-filefolder-using-powershell/2158)

```
$username = "exampleuser"

$permissionArgs = "domain\$username", "FullControl", "allow"
$permissionRule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule $permissionArgs
$acl = Get-Acl 'C:\Users\username1\Desktop\TESTING2'
$acl.SetAccessRule($permissionRule)
Set-ACL -Path 'C:\Users\username1\Desktop\TESTING2' -AclObject $acl
```

When I use CACLS to see the permissions I get the following output. (usernames+domain blurred) [image: CACLS output]

Can anyone advise how to make the first user listed have the same permissions as the last?

Comment: I used this to understand permissions, please correct me if wrong: http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/53503-45-interpreting-cacls-output

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to include the inheritance parameter while definig the ACL rule like the below one.

```
$Folderpath='Destination Folder'
$user_account='User Acccount'
$Acl = Get-Acl $Folderpath
$Ar = New-Object system.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule($user_account, "FullControl", "ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit", "None", "Allow")
$Acl.Setaccessrule($Ar)
Set-Acl $Folderpath $Acl
```

Hope this HElps.